# CoreOS - expose host ports to VPN

Tags: docker, networking, coreos, openvpn, tun

I run docker Openvpn container in CoreOS:

```
docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun ...
```

Container connects to VPN as client and other VPN clients can ping the container. It runs normal `openvpn` process inside it with `dev tun` option in config.

My task is to make **host ports** (`-p`ublushed ports from any other containers) on this machine available to other VPN clients, via that `tun0` inside VPN client container (so it must be host's to set up routing?). How to implement this?

Comment: Your main container is an openvpn client connected to a remote vpn server ? and you want other connect through this container without running openvpn itself (becuase its already running in the container) ?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to build a VPN-only visible coreos worker, e.g. machine should expose everything it has to the VPN network it is connected to as a client. I use https://github.com/tsaikd/docker-openvpn

Comment: So me as a user should access a service through it because it requires vpn ip and so on, right ? I have built similar scenario before i am just ensuring before submitting an answer :D

Comment: Yes, some few ports will be accessed directly of course, but most are vpn-only services for other machines in VPN. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will assume that you have a container connected to a VPN server and you need to access a server through this container due to IP restrictions and so on.

1- In case you are using Bridge Network which is the default when you run a container:

In order to achieve you will need to have IPTables installed inside the container and after starting the VPN connection run the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And from the host machine where you want to access a service you can use `iproute` command to route the connection through the container as below:

> Assuming you want to access a remote server with IP 192.168.0.20 through a container with IP: 172.17.0.4

```
ip route add 192.168.0.20 via 172.17.0.4
```

Now whenever you access the server which is 192.168.0.20 it will be through the VPN client inside your container.

2- You can pass `--network=host` to `docker run` and in this case you wont need any extra steps to do as the connection will be routed through the VPN by default

---

**Update:**

Given that you have a Container **Y** with port 9000 and accessible through Container **X**.

Container **X** is connected to a VPN.

A User connected to the same VPN wants to access Container **Y** and he should go through Container **X**, then you need to apply the following firewall rules inside Container **X**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE 

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination $CONTAINER_Y_DOCKER_IP 

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $CONTAINER_Y_DOCKER_IP --dport 9000 -j SNAT --to-source $CONTAINER_X_DOCKER_IP

iptables -A FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d $CONTAINER_Y_DOCKER_IP --dport 9000 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Let me try. I actually found chain `DOCKER` in container's iptables that includes my publushed ports, by the way. I don't yet understand what's this. I just used `--network host` alongside with `--device` and `--cap-add`.

Comment: My scenario above applies on a bridge network (the default docker setup), if you intend to use host network then by default the communication will be routed through it no additional steps are needed

Comment: True! I can use my ports as `localhost` inside VPN container already. Will check why other VPN clients can't knock them from their side. It is surely the container trouble, not client's.

Comment: If you are meant to use a container with bridge network then the first method will be help you achieve that

Comment: Thank you! Both your suggestions are correct. However, i cannot access custom TCP port `9000` from another VPN client. I get connection refused error when doing `telnet 10.8.0.2 9000` (the ip of container vpn), while have iptables policy ACCEPT both in docker host and docker vpn container. Could you tell me what i can be missing? I use bridge network(default, without `--network ..`)